# How to remove first occurrence of a letter?

Tags: python

I know how to remove the first occurrence of a letter using splicing, but I'm trying to achieve this without using any of the string functions like splicing, .find(), .count(), etc. I can't seem to figure out how you complete it without splicing.

Here's what I currently have with splicing that works correctly:

```
s1 = ''
s2 = len(remWord)
for i in range(s2):
    if (remWord[i] == remLetter):
        s1 = remWord[0:i] + remWord[i + 1:s2]
return s1
```

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you do not remove anything if the letter is not contained in the string, so you can use the following code:

#### Strictly not using splicing

```
new_string = ''
found = False

for i in range(len(remWord)):
    if remWord[i] != remLetter or found:
        new_string += remWord[i]
    else:
        found = True
```

#### If you are allowed to use splicing

```
new_string = ''

for i in range(len(remWord)):
    if remWord[i] != remLetter:
        new_string += remWord[i]
    else:
        break

new_string += remWord[i + 1:]
```

Comment: Where did you get the c from?

Comment: @DenisJohnson, there is no `c` anymore, maybe you should refresh the page.

Comment: This is still splicing, is it not? You accumulate the first half, then use a slice for the second.

Comment: My other suggestion would be to replace the for loop producing an index with something more idiomatic, such as ‘for letter in remWord’, or if you need the index, use enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

You should stop the processing as soon as you encounter the first letter, use a `break` for this purpose.

```
remWord = 'this is the word to process'
remLetter = 's'
s1 = ''
s2 = len(remWord)
for i in range(s2):
    if (remWord[i] == remLetter):
        s1 = remWord[0:i] + remWord[i + 1:s2]
        break
print s1
```

**output:**

```
$ python firstletter.py 
thi is the word to process
```

If you omit the `break`, your output will be like this

```
$ python firstletter.py 
this is the word to proces
```

As the if clause will be satisfied for the last encounter of the `remLetter` present in your input string

Comment: my solution is correct when the letter that should be removed is not in the string because yours just prints an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are sequence types, so we can do this (mostly) with just sequence operations.

```
seen = False
chars = ''
for ch in remWord:
    if ch == remLetter and not seen:
        seen = True
    else:
        chars += ch
```

The trouble with this is it’s a little expensive because you’re creating a new string each time. Alternatively you can make chars a list and use StringIO, or ''.join if you can get away with it.